# HTML/CSS - ScrollBar missing

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging

Problem:
The **scrollbar is missing** on my (social-media) website. It's because of the *"position: fixed;"* thing. Everything was fine before. I tried to set overflow to *"overflow: auto;"* where I set *"position: fixed"*. But it only made things worse, and still... **no scrollbar**.

I tried to create two different divs (one for a menu, with pages etc. (class: "row") and other for user stuff (settings, inbox, profile etc.) (class: "row2"))).

HTML:

```
<body>

<!-- HEADER, LOGO, SLOGAN, HR -->
<header>
<h1>PTRN</h1>
<h2>something</h2>
<hr class="headerhr">
</header>

<!-- SIDE BAR 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#">#1</a>
    <a href="#">#2</a>
    <a href="#">#3</a>
    <a href="#">#4</a>
    <a href="#">#5</a>
    <a href="#">#6</a>
    <a href="#">#7</a>
    <a href="#">#8</a>
    <a href="#">#9</a>
    <a href="#">#10</a>

     <div class="searchbar">
       <p class="searchplaceholder">Search</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SIDE BAR 2 -->
<div class="container2">
<img class="menu1" src="file:///C:/Users/calex/Downloads/download.%20(1).jpg">

  <div class="row2">
    <a href="#">Inbox</a>
    <a href="#">Notifications</a>
    <a href="#">Meetings</a>
    <a href="#">Inbox</a>
    <p class="shared">Shared</p>
    <a href="#">Documents</a>
    <a href="#">Photos</a>

  <div class="row2_2">
    <a href="#">Settings</a>
    <a href="#">Help & Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- POST SAMPLE -->
<div class="container3">
<img src="https://tiffanieanne.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Batter-Spencer-Best-Views-in-San-Francisco-SF-Instagram-Worthy-Photo-Spots-SF-Photography-tiffanieanne.com_-768x954.jpg" alt="San Francisco, CA, USA">
  <div class="container4">
    <p class="username_post">Chita Cosmin</p>
     <p class="jobb">Founder & CEO of Pictoren Platforms, Inc. since 2020</p>
      <img class="prpic" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540512663861-0dcbe11ab7a3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1yZWxhdGVkfDE1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="Profile Pic">

    <div class="container5">
      <b class="fakebutton">Info</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
/* BODY */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    background: #a9c4db;
}

/* BACKGROUND NOTE: #acb6b7 */

/* LOGO AND SLOGAN */
h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin: 0;
    background: url(https://data.whicdn.com/images/342108134/original.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip:text;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 49.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin: 0;
    background: url(https://data.whicdn.com/images/342108134/original.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip:text;
}

/* HEAEDER SEPARATOR */
.headerhr {
    border: none;
    height: 3px;
    width: 40.6cm;
    background-color: #9700FF;
    margin-top: 90px;
}

/* HEADER */
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: black;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

/* SIDE BAR 1 */
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 110px;
  left: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 800px;
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 87px;
  top: 190px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row a:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.searchbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
  z-index: 4000;
  top: 150px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 37px;
  top: 135px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.searchplaceholder {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #8a8a8a;
  top: 135px;
  left: 95px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container bi-house {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  size: 250px;
}

/* SIDE BAR 2 */
.container2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 110px;
  right: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 800px;
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row2 a:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.shared {
  opacity: 40%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.row2_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 160px;
  bottom: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu1 {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 22px;
  margin-top: 0%;
  z-index: 2000;
  margin-left: 1%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  overflow: auto;

}

/* POST SAMPLE */
.container3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 147%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 700px;
  width: 640px;
  border-radius: 22px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15.43%;
  border-radius: 22px;
  margin-right: 5.6%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #efeded; 
}

.container4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 70px;
  width: 570px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #efeded;
  z-index: 999;
}

.username_post {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  right: 860px;
  top: 137px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.prpic {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 10%;
  max-height: 10%;
  float: left;
  top: -100px;
  left: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  clip-path: circle();
  overflow: auto;
}

.jobb {
  position: fixed;
  color: #878787;
  font-size: 13px;
  top: 165px;
  left: 561px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fakebutton{
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 17px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin: 0;
  background: url(https://data.whicdn.com/images/342108134/original.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  top: 174px;
  right: 500px;
  z-index: 1001;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container5 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #9700FF;
  right: 12px;
  top: 19px;
}
```

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe try `overflow-y:scroll;` or `overflow-x:scroll;` instead of auto.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'overflow' to work, then try adding 'max-height' property to that element in your css code.

Comment: It doesn't work,